# Xcode Swift 3 Picker: Putting the DataSource in ViewDidLoad

Tags: swift, delegates, iboutlet, viewdidload, picker

I am trying to set up a picker that would display different results based on certain conditions. The only issue is that I need to put the `dataSource` (picker data that will display) outside the `viewDidLoad`. I need the `viewDidLoad` to load the appropriate data if the condition was met. However, with code dealing with pickers that I've seen, it seems the `dataSource` array is placed outside the `viewDidLoad` (I presume so the delegate methods can use that value). I am just wondering if I can place this `dataSource` into `viewDidLoad` so that it would recognize it, or if there was a way to run a Switch or If statement outside the `viewDidLoad` and in the class.

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class VC: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    var pickerData = [String]()

    @IBOutlet weak var namePicker: UIPickerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        namePicker.dataSource = self
        namePicker.delegate = self


        //here I want the picker to show something different depending on the value of nameOfPerson. I changed the order of the array because the picker selects the first name of the array as the default. 
        switch nameOfPerson
        {
        case "Carly": 
            let pickerData = ["Carly","Jeff","Bob","Anita"]
        case "Jeff": 
            let pickerData = ["Jeff","Carly","Bob","Anita"]
        case "Bob": 
            let pickerData = ["Bob","Carly","Jeff","Anita"]
        case "Anita": 
            let pickerData = ["Anita","Carly","Jeff","Bob"]
        }
    }
   func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerData.count
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return pickerData[row]
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some code to your question? I've read it a couple times, and I'm still confused about what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am just wondering if I can place this dataSource into viewDidLoad so that it would recognize it, or if there was a way to run a Switch or If statement outside the viewDidLoad and in the class

No. The data source methods must be *methods*, i.e. functions at the top level of the class, in order for Objective-C to see them. Therefore the data itself must be visible to the data source methods, and the only coherent way to share data between `viewDidLoad` and the data source methods is as a property, like your `var pickerData`.

What's wrong with *your* code is the `let`:

```
    case "Carly": 
        let pickerData = ["Carly","Jeff","Bob","Anita"]
    case "Jeff": 
        let pickerData = ["Jeff","Carly","Bob","Anita"]
    case "Bob": 
        let pickerData = ["Bob","Carly","Jeff","Anita"]
    case "Anita": 
        let pickerData = ["Anita","Carly","Jeff","Bob"]
    }
```

Delete the term `let` from each of those cases! Otherwise you are just setting a temporary local variable `pickerData`, which is not what you want to do. You want to set the *property* that you declared like this:

```
var pickerData = [String]()
```

....and your code is not doing that! What you want is this:

```
case "Carly": 
    self.pickerData = ["Carly","Jeff","Bob","Anita"]
case "Jeff": 
    self.pickerData = ["Jeff","Carly","Bob","Anita"]
case "Bob": 
    self.pickerData = ["Bob","Carly","Jeff","Anita"]
case "Anita": 
    self.pickerData = ["Anita","Carly","Jeff","Bob"]
}
```

(Plus you need a `default` case, of course.)

Then, at the end, just to be on the safe side, reload the data:

```
self.namePicker.reloadAllComponents()
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad to help. Note how this shows the importance of including your code in the question. Generalities are pointless; impossible to help unless we can see the actual problem!

Answer (score 0):

Datasource needs to be set while the view loads, though you can load it anywhere, where you need it.

Inside `viewDidLoad`

```
picker.datasource = self
```

Anywhere, you can set the actual data;

```
picker.dataArray = "example, anything"
```

I'm not sure I understand you completely. Please let me know if you were not looking for this.